# How does $\sum_{k=0}^{n-p} \sum_{i=0}^{k} C^{p-1+i}_i\cdot C^{n-(p+i)}_{k-i}\cdot(p+i)$ simplify to $p\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-p} C^{n+1}_k$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Given equation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-p} \sum_{i=0}^{k} C^{p-1+i}_i\cdot C^{n-(p+i)}_{k-i}\cdot(p+i)$$
here

I can simplify this to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-p} \sum_{i=0}^{k} p\cdot C^{p+i}_i\cdot C^{n-(p+i)}_{k-i}$$

But i can't go any further 
I need to simplify this thing to:

$$p\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-p} C^{n+1}_k$$

How to reach here?

Comment: Do you know generating functions? The inner sum is a convolution of two generating functions

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/890770/573047) and there replace $l$ with $i$, $n$ with $n+1$, $j$ with $n+1-k$, $M$ with $p+1$, to get $\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{p+i}{i} \binom{n-p-i}{k-i} = \binom{n+1}{k}$.

Comment: What's $C_i^k$?

Comment: @diger that notation is equivalent to the binomial coefficient, $\binom{k}{i}$

Comment: ok, thanks. Never seen it.

Comment: First, notice that $\binom{p+i-1}{i}(p+i)=p\binom{p+i}{i}$.

Comment: @AlanAbraham I only know some very basics about generating functions. I don't know convolution

Comment: @Aditi You can use the proofs in the post BillyJoe linked. The third answer is the generating function proof.